# Solution for detecting a magnetic field

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, embedded

I have an Arduino based circuit that performs a mechanical job and I'd like the circuit to turn on when it detects a magnetic field. I want to use a magnet as a trigger for the circuit. When a magnet is attached to something like say a stick and put near the circuit board I'd like it to detect the magnetic field and turn on.

I have learnt that an operational amplifier can be used for this purpose but need guidance on how to do it as I am a novice in embedded systems & electronics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way or another, you need some kind of transducer that can make a electrical signal that is a function of magnetic field strength.  No, a opamp can't do this.  A opamp may be useful in tranforming the raw signal from such a transducer into something the microcontroller can read, but by itself a opamp is not a magnetic sensor.

Two possibilities come to mind:

**Reed switch**.  These are the bare switch parts of a relay, usually enclosed in a small glass envelope.  The right magnetic field causes the switch to close.  This will be the simplest solution if you have a strong enough magnetic field.  This usually means a reasonable permanent magnet can be placed with a half inch or so of the reed switch.

**Hall effect sensor**.  The underlying physics of these sensors creates a small electrical signal proportional to the magnetic field in a particular direction.  However, you rarely get bare Hall sensors directly.  Usually they are integrated into a single package with something that either makes a reasonable size voltage proportional to magnetic field strength, or provides a digital output, usually with some hysteresis, to indicate presence or abscence of some level of magnetic field.  Allegro is a supplier that makes a lot of these things with various options.

Comment: The supplier Olin mentioned is Allegro. (http://www.allegromicro.com)  Another sensor manufacturer that I have used in the past is Melexis. (http://www.melexis.com)

Comment: Note that if you use a reed switch, you can build a device that requires no standby power. On the other hand, a Hall-effect sensor needs to be powered all the time.